# Node.js connecting again after calling close with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Using the official and latest version of the Node.js MongoDB driver 3.2.4 and doing

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
    poolSize: 10,
    j: true,
    reconnectInterval: 2000,
    reconnectTries: 150
});
client.connect();

setTimeout(() => {
   client.close();

   setTimeout(() => {
       client.connect();
   }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

I would expect this to connect, wait a second, disconnect, wait a second, and then connect again.

However I am getting the error:

```
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
server instance pool was destroyed
```

Is it not possible to connect again after calling close?

Comment: It sounds like MongoClient instance is gced on close.. I would try to create new instance before connect..

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't wait for `mongo` to actually connect. You should use the `client` inside a callback for `connect`.

Read here about how to connect using this driver [Github Docs](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#connect-to-mongodb)